# Astyanax Cassandra Double type precision

Tags: cql3, astyanax, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I'm trying to get a Double value from a Cassandra table with a double type column. I've created the table in CQL3 syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE data_double (
    datetime timestamp,
    value double,
    primary key (datetime)
    );
```

I've inserted a row:

```
INSERT INTO data_double (datetime,  value) VALUES ('111111111', 123.456);
```

When I do:

```
SELECT * from data_double;
```

I get that the value is **123.46**

Why is the value rounded?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `cqlsh` utility by default will only display 5 digits of precision for floating point numbers.

You can increase this by creating a cqlshrc file with contents like the following:

```
[ui]
float_precision = 10
```

The [cqlsh docs page](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html) provides more details on the available options.

**Update:** The location of the cqlshrc file changed at some point in Cassandra. The new default location is `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc`. You can also use a file in a different location with the `--cqlshrc` command-line option.

Comment: Are you sure its `. cqlshrc ` ? datastax referes to it as `cqlshrc ` here https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshUsingCqlshrc.html?hl=cqlshrc

Comment: @simo thanks for pointing that out; the location did change somewhere along the way, so I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: so there's no way to this within the select statement?

Comment: @AFischbein no there isn't; the cqlshrc file is the only way I'm aware of. Keep in mind this is just the cqlsh shell behavior; when you run with your own application the driver will return the full precision of all floating values.