# Import decimal to cassandra using pig

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I've been banging my head against the wall for awhile on this one and it seems so simple.  I know I'm missing something key here.

Using Pig 0.12.1.2.1.2.0-402, Cassandra 2.0.9, I am trying to import a precision number (that needs to remain at the same precision) into Cassandra.

The data itself is exported from Oracle using Sqoop and the numbers look fine.

For example: The data in question is 38.62782.  If I import using a pig double or float, precision is lost, which is not acceptable in this case.  I've tried multiple combinations and pig's bigdecimal seems to be a perfect fit, but I cannot get it to work as I continually get the following:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats  - ERROR: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray
```

So I don't understand what I need to do to make this work.  I just want the 38.62782 from Oracle (and the Sqoop file) to appear as 38.62782 without making the Cassandra column a text field.

Sample pig:

```
DEFINE UnixToISO org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.UnixToISO();
DEFINE ISOToUnix org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix();
DEFINE CustomToDate2Args com.mine.pig.udf.CustomToDate2Args();
DEFINE ToBoolean com.mine.pig.udf.ToBoolean();
DEFINE CustomCqlStorage com.mine.pig.CustomCqlStorage();
DEFINE s2d InvokeForDouble( 'java.lang.Double.parseDouble', 'String' );

oracle_load = LOAD '$input_file' USING PigStorage('     ') AS (
  NAME:chararray,
  MYDOUBLE:chararray,
  MYFLOAT:float,
  MYDECIMAL:bytearray,
  MYTEXT:chararray);

oracle_data = FOREACH oracle_load generate
  (NAME=='null'?null:NAME) as NAME,
  MYDOUBLE,
  MYFLOAT,
  MYDECIMAL,
  MYTEXT;


R = FOREACH oracle_data GENERATE TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('name',NAME)), TOTUPLE(
  s2d(MYDOUBLE),
  MYFLOAT,
  MYDECIMAL,
  MYTEXT);


STORE R into 'cql://$cass_user:$cass_pass@$cass_keyspace/mydoubletest?output_query=update+$cass_keyspace.mydoubletest+set+mydouble+%3D+%3F,myfloat+%3D+%3F,mydecimal+%3D+%3F,mytext+%3D+%3F' USING CustomCqlStorage();
```

and the table definition I'm trying out just for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE mydoubletest (
  name text,
  mydecimal decimal,
  mydouble double,
  myfloat float,
  mytext text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((name))
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Comment: Here's a doc on Cassandra CQL data types, and what they map to.  See if you can find a match in here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html

Comment: Yes, it says that decimal in Cassandra maps to java.math.BigDecimal, which makes it all the more frustrating that I can't just use "MYDECIMAL:bigdecimal" above (when I do that I get the exception noted).  There's also no InvokeToBigDecimal option, so I'm not sure if I need to do something with UDF, but it seems like such a circuitous way to do something so seemingly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was very different than the answer I was looking for.

First off, creating a UDF did work for this.  Two things though, is that we were using a Custom Cql Storage routine which did not take BigDecimal into account.  Second, after further exploration because of a separate reason it turns out that the issue was with cqlsh.  The fields **were not actually losing precision**.

However, the answer to *my* overall problem was exactly what was listed here: 
[Astyanax Cassandra Double type precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573599/astyanax-cassandra-double-type-precision)